Función bool me devuelve siempre verdadero
Tengo que comparar 2 arreglos/vectores, y ver si tienen los mismos valores utilizando recursividad y la respuesta debe salir de una función que retorne un valor booleano, el problema es que siempre me devuelve true, alguien me puede ayudar?
public static bool IGUALDAD(int[] vector1, int[] vector2, int cant)
{
    if (cant == 0)
    {
        return true || false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (vector1[cant] != vector2[cant])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            IGUALDAD(vector1, vector2, cant - 1);
        }
    }
    return false || true;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cant;
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el largo de los vectores");
    cant = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] vector1 = new int[cant];
    int[] vector2 = new int[cant];
    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un valor para el primer vector");
        vector1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un valor para el segundo vector");
        vector2[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    int contador = 0;
    if (IGUALDAD(vector1, vector2, cant - 1) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Los vectores no son iguales");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Los vectores  son iguales");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}


creo que el error en la logica del primer if esta mal (return true || false;) es decir si es 0 puede retornanr falso o verdadero?

Hola Hugo, bienvenido, como te indica @colcrt, el primer "if" siempre devuelve "true", y como en cada recursión vas restando "1" a "cant", está siempre terminará valiendo "cero" por lo que entrará en el... la sentencia "true || false", primero evalua el primer término, si este es verdadero devuelve "true" y si es falso, devuelve el segundo término.

Y el mismo problema también al final de IGUALDAD()

Tienes varios errores en tu función IGUALDAD:

true || false y false||true serán true SIEMPRE (no importa el orden), por lo que colocar cualquiera de esas expresiones es equivalente a colocar simplemente true

IGUALDAD(vector1,vector2,cant-1); no retorna nada, debería ser


return IGUALDAD(vector1,vector2,cant-1);

Y es esto lo que te está ocasionando problema, porque esa función se ejecuta pero no retorna su resultado, entonces el programa sigue de largo hasta llegar al último return false||true;, que como te explique antes es siempre true
Luego tienes 2 errores de "conceptos"

Tienes una variable cant, uno pensaría que es la cantidad (el largo del array), pero lo que es en realidad es el index (índice), que si bien tienen algo que ver lo uno con lo otro, son cosas distintas. Esto lleva a una confusión, en la cual tú mismo has caído cuando haces if (cant == 0) uno podría pensar que te refieres a un array vacío y no es así te refieres al índice cero, el cual no estas comparando sus valores para determinar su igualdad, por lo que tu algoritmo siempre fallará en el último caso, es decir este array [1,2,3] con este otro [2,2,3] lo tomara como iguales, porque no compara nunca el primer elemento. Debes cambiar if(index == 0) porif(index < 0)

En C# a diferencia de C/C++ los vectores responden al concepto matemático de vectores, y existen las estructuras Vector, Vector1, Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Vector64, etc para la operación de vectores (sumas, restas, cruz, etc). En C# arreglos y vectores son cosas distintas, lo que tú tienes son arreglos o arrays


El algoritmo corregido:
public static bool IGUALDAD(int[] array1, int[] array2, int index)
{
    if (index < 0) //condicion de parada, necesaria para cualquier función recursiva. Es index < 0, porque se debe comparar siempre los elementos del indice cero
        return true;
    else if (array1[index] != array2[index]) //si encontró un elemento distinto, es falso y no hay nada mas que hacer
        return false;
    return IGUALDAD(array1, array2, index - 1); //seguimos recorriendo
}

Se que este es un ejercicio académico, pero no sobra saber que C# cuenta con una función SequenceEqual que permite comparar el contendido de 2 colecciones:
public static bool IGUALDAD(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    return array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
}

